# Macro compile error – Next without for

Tags: vba, vbscript, compile

I have a macro that has a compile error that I don’t know how to fix. It;s the second last line “next” that gets highlighted and the message comes up “Next without for”. What code do I need to make this macro work?

```
Sub MOVEDOWN1()

Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    n = sht.Range("J2")

    For Each cell In sht.Range("P21:P52,U21:U52,Z21:Z52,AE21:AE52,AJ21:AJ52,AO21:AO52,AT21:AT52,AY21:AY52,BD21:BD52,BI21:BI52").Cells

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
            Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " & cell.Address

            'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
         Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            'make sure not to add before col L
            If rngDest.Column < 14 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 14)

            cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest

              Rem Move the cell contents to the next cell

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then
         Cells(irow + 1, icol).Insert Shift:=xlDown
         Cells(irow, icol).Copy Cells(irow + 1, icol)
         Cells(irow, icol).Clear

            Exit For

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing an `end if`

Comment: @shawn Thanks for you're reply. I have added a End if statement before Exit for and it compiles fine now but the macro doesn't do anything. any comment? Thanks again.

Comment: `next` should be `next cell`

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for your reply. i just tried "Nexr cell" and still nothing happens. No compile errors just nothing happens!

Comment: You are missing another `end if`

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry but I'm new to coding but leaning lots. So the code would be as follows:                         End If                                                                          Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub                                                                           No compile error but still nothing happens. Thanks so much for your help. Karen

Comment: @KARENKENDALL I don't know what your code is supposed to do, and I'm not a VBA expert. All I know is that you need another `end if`. You should work out if the `if`s are meant to be nested or not. It's your code. Or did you just grab it from somewhere without knowing how it is supposed to work?

Comment: You might want to read [Debugging VBA Code • My Online Training Hub](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code)

Comment: Update the code is the question

Comment: @shawn Thank-you for your reply. The issue is not a compile error but a code issue. The goal of the code is to move the contents down to the cell below. I'm just not where the problem is.

Comment: @KARENKENDALL Let me try again: Please update the code within the question. You have three `IF` statements (one of which is a one-liner so doesn't require an `END IF`), but only one `END IF`. If you want feedback on code we need to know what the current state of the code is.

Comment: @shawn Hi, I would like to thank-you for your help. You got me thinking and working on my code and as a result I have solved the issue. This posting can be closed. Thanks again.